# Apache conf or .htaccess rule to redirect a 404 to another location for a certain file type

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I use subversion and don't want to check out over 1 GB of images onto each developers desktop so how can I just have one central image server and have apache push 404's just from *.jpg for example to this other server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch (.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png))$ http://the.central.server/$1
```

Comment: That would just return a fixed file, I think the OP is asking that if the file is not available, redirect to another server.

Comment: Right. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with either [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), or if you just have a single folder of images, configure Apache as a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with just reverse-proxing the image directory, but what's so bad about an extra 2GB (that you subversion overhead)?

Any attempt to partition the data just leaves more chances for code error.